# GPS issues, location permission - one app only

Tags: gps, nexus-one, permissions

One app ([Dino Dominion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.colopl.dinous)) will not register location but will express this complaint: "In order to register your location, please turn the location permission setting on in the application settings."

The app itself has permissions (told to me when installed and when Managing Applications) of coarse and fine location. I didn't think these permissions needed "turning on" - other apps are using GPS without problems.

I asked the app developer, but all they said was "You have to turn on location permission on your device" and "GPS needs to be valid on the side of your device."

I couldn't see any relevant settings anywhere. The GPS is working fine. Also, other users of the app seem to have no problems.

I have HTC Nexus One and Android 2.2.2.

Comment: Do other location-apps on your device work w/o trouble, e.g. *Google Maps*? I guess the dev is referring to the system settings (*System -> Location & Security*), where you can tell the *Android system* which services (GPS, network-based) it should enable. Anything enabled there?

Comment: Other location-apps work fine. Under "My Location" in the menu you mentioned, "Use wireless networks" and "Use GPS satellites" are both enabled. That's why I'm so puzzled.

Comment: Sounds like the issue is the app. I wonder if the developer set the API level too low and is using a function not available for 2.2.2.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this question that I'd asked a while ago. In case anyone is curious, the problem was that I had mock locations switched on. The app didn't like it (for potential cheating by pretending I was elsewhere) but it would have been nice if the app's error message was clear about it, though.